# Salesforce as IdP with ADFS 2.0

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I’m trying to use the free developer edition (http://developer.force.com/) of and setup a demo SAML Idp for testing with my ADFS 2.0 + SP. So far I’ve managed to enabled SAML support, and created a connected app. Everything works relatively well right up to login. After login, I’m redirected back to my ADFS but I’m facing following error

> Failed to process the Web request because the request is not valid.
>   Cannot get protocol message from HTTP query. The following errors
>   occurred when trying to parse incoming HTTP request:
>
> Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlMessageException:
>   MSIS7015: This request does not contain the expected protocol message
>   or incorrect protocol parameters were found according to the HTTP SAML
>   protocol bindings.

Here’s my settings of the application

```
Entity Id   http://staging/adfs/services/trust
ACS URL https://staging/adfs/ls/
Subject Type    User ID
Name ID Format  urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress
Issuer  https://ttt-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
Service Provider Certificate
```

The ones I’m not sure are ACS URL and Service provider Certificate. Thoughts?

Following are salesforce related resources about setting it as Idp and associated Sp configurations.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=service_provider_define.htm&language=en_US

Comment: In general, when trying to troubleshoot ADFS/SAML issues I've found it's helpful to record your network traffic with the dev tools of your browser, grab the SAML Requests/Responses and run them through a base64 decoder to check that the values you expect are being sent and received.

Answer (score 0):

We have done the similar configuration but with PingOne instead of  ADFS2.0. But the steps would be same. In our case our ACS Url was like: **https://sso.connect.pingidentity.com/sso/sp/ACS.saml2**  and we had to upload one PingOne certificate at salesforce end for verifying request Signatures. 
From salesforce side we had generated a Default Idp Certificate and passed that to Ping one.